# Updating just one value with update_option in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

There are many options within an 'option' in the 'wp_options' table. This option, `second_option`, contains three parameters and consequently has three values. The values are, for example, as follows:

```
{s:12:"manual";s:0:""; s:8:"currency";s:3:"USD";s:14:"state";s:2:"nn";}
```

I want to update the value of the second parameter, and that is `'currency'`, yet whenever I want to update just this portion, Wordpress just updates whole of the option and the first option and the third, that is `'manual'` and `'state'` are deleted and just remains what I am updating, that is `'currency'`. I use the following piece of code:

```
$sets = get_option( 'second_option' );
$sets['currency'] = 'some_value';
update_option('second_option', $sets);
```

Is there a way to update just the option `'currency'` without affecting other parameters, that is `'manual'` and `'state'`?

Thanks in advance.